# ActionBarSherlock overlapping on tab navigation and ActionMode

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a strange problem with ActionBarSherlock, using tab navigation and an Action Mode.

Repeat the problem is very simple, I use demo code to generate following example activity:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionMode;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private ActionMode actionMode = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(com.actionbarsherlock.R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
            tab.setText("Tab " + i);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
        }

        actionMode = startActionMode(new TestActionMode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


    private final class TestActionMode implements ActionMode.Callback {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            menu.add("Add").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_input_add).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
            menu.add("Search").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_search_category_default).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

}
```

It works correctly on Android 4.0 (tested on real device and emulator), but on Jelly Bean (tested only on emulator) I have the following behavior.

- Application start (portrait mode) and it works correctly;
- I rotate application and it works correctly;
- I rotate again application and now tab navigation and ActionMode are overlapped (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf1VG.png).

Sometimes (but rarely), all works perfectly, especially if I have all animations enable in Dev. Setting (usually I disable all animation).

I'm using ActionBarSherlock 4.4.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, because I really don't understand where I make a mistake.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I am having a similar problem using appcompat where the tabs overlay the actionmode on an HTC One X, and hopefully a sherlock solution could help me track down the appcompat solution.

Comment: @ChrisM If you are still interested and have not found solution, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across to the same issue. After wasting few days on it, found out that this weird behavior is caused by UX flaw described in [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36191) and, in fact, has nothing to do with [ABS (action bar sherlock)](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).

The most reliable workaround seems to be using reflection to control how action bar should be rendered:

```
/**
 * On Android 3.0 and above, while using the ActionBar tabbed navigation style, the tabs sometimes appear above the action bar.
 * This helper method allows you to control the 'hasEmbeddedTabs' behaviour.
 * A value of true will put the tabs inside the ActionBar, a value of false will put it above or below the ActionBar.
 *
 * You should call this method while initialising your ActionBar tabs.
 * Don't forget to also call this method during orientation changes (in the onConfigurationChanged() method).
 *
 * @param inActionBar
 * @param inHasEmbeddedTabs
 */
public static void setHasEmbeddedTabs(Object inActionBar, final boolean inHasEmbeddedTabs)
{
        // get the ActionBar class
        Class<?> actionBarClass = inActionBar.getClass();

        // if it is a Jelly Bean implementation (ActionBarImplJB), get the super class (ActionBarImplICS)
        if ("android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplJB".equals(actionBarClass.getName()))
        {
                actionBarClass = actionBarClass.getSuperclass();
        }

        try
        {
                // try to get the mActionBar field, because the current ActionBar is probably just a wrapper Class
                // if this fails, no worries, this will be an instance of the native ActionBar class or from the ActionBarImplBase class
                final Field actionBarField = actionBarClass.getDeclaredField("mActionBar");
                actionBarField.setAccessible(true);
                inActionBar = actionBarField.get(inActionBar);
                actionBarClass = inActionBar.getClass();
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {}
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
        catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {}

        try
        {
                // now call the method setHasEmbeddedTabs, this will put the tabs inside the ActionBar
                // if this fails, you're on you own <img src="http://www.blogc.at/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_wink.gif" alt=";-)" class="wp-smiley"> 
                final Method method = actionBarClass.getDeclaredMethod("setHasEmbeddedTabs", new Class[] { Boolean.TYPE });
                method.setAccessible(true);
                method.invoke(inActionBar, new Object[]{ inHasEmbeddedTabs });
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e)        {}
        catch (InvocationTargetException e) {}
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {}
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
}
```

The above code was taken from [this blog post](http://www.blogc.at/2014/01/23/android-tabs-appear-above-or-below-actionbar/).